# Irregular Range Average Based on Common Value in ID

Tags: excel, range, average

I'm trying to average groups of numbers which share a common value in one column but do not have a consistent number of rows. Simplified example of the problem below:

```
ID    Value  
Cat     2  
Cat     3  
Cat     5  
Cat     8  
Dog     1  
Dog     6  
Dog     3  
Fish    3  
Fish    9
```

So I'd like to find a single average of the values for each of the groups `Cat`, `Dog`, and `Fish`.

Note: I have just over 13,000 rows  and 596 unique IDs shared amongst those 13,000 data (all positive decimals).

Comment: Use a pivot Table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Select your data.
- Go to `Insert`, `Pivot Table`
- Select a destination for the Pivot Table
- Drag the fields from the field list such that `ID` is a Row Label and `Value` is in the Values section:

[image: Pivot]

- Click on the downward arrow beside the `Value` field and click on `Value field Settings`.
- Change the `Summarise` operation to `Average`.